# Checking if two Objects containing Series are equal

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to compares two `Cashflow` Objects which just contain a `Series` as part of a Unit Test.

In the Unit Test I have the following where `cashflowobj_1` and `cashflowobj_2` are the `Cashflow` Objects containing the `Series`:

```
self.assert_(cashflowobj_1==cashflowobj_2)
```

The two Series look exactly the same as can be seen below, but the test returns `Series are not equal`, so I'm wondering if there might be an issue in the function I am using to check their equality. `cashflowobj_1.amounts` and `cashflowobj_2.amounts` are the respective `Series`:

`cashflowobj_1.amounts`:

```
     1983-05-15      1
     1983-11-15      1
     1984-05-15      1
     1984-11-15     101
```

`cashflowobj_2.amounts`:

```
     1983-05-15      1
     1983-11-15      1
     1984-05-15      1
     1984-11-15     101
```

Function used to check if the `Cashflow`  Objects are equal, which is in the `Cashflow` Class:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    '''
    Series being equal
    '''
    if ((len(self.amounts) == len(other.amounts))) and ((all(i in self.amounts for i in other.amounts))):
        print('Series are equal')
        return(1)
    else:
        print('Series are not equal')
        return(0)
```

**Edit**: To address @matt's question: The indices are both `datetime.date()` Objects. And the values are `float64`.

Comment: What type of object are in the `amounts` attributes? If they're regular lists or tuples, the `i in self.amounts` part will check using regular equality, so if those objects don't have `__eq__` also implemented correctly, they won't match.

Comment: @matts Thanks. The indices are both `datetime.date()` Objects. And the values are `float64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you just want to check if the Series are equal? Assuming you're talking about Pandas.Series.

Using the [Series.equals()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.equals.html) function.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    '''
    Series being equal
    '''
    if self.amounts.equals(other.amounts)
        print('Series are equal')
        return(1)
    else:
        print('Series are not equal')
        return(0)
```